# \input{...} is ignored with beamer option ignorenonframetext

Tags: beamer, input, beamerarticle

I'm using `beamer` to create my slides and wanted to use `beamerarticle` to create written paper which is not just printed slides 3 on 1 page.

The option `ignorenonframetext` for the `beamer` class forces it to ignore any text but `\section{}` etc. that is not inside a `frame` environment. This is intended for interaction with the `beamerarticle` class to edit all information (frames and additional text) at the same place.

Unfortunately the `\input{}` command is ignored as well, making it impossible to organize my document in the usual way, i.e. one file for any section for example.

Is there any additional option to activate this kind of "infrastructure" command in `beamer`?

**Example**

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{scrartcl} \usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\title{Test slides}
\author{Christoph Juengling}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\input{sec-one}

This is explaning text at the end of the first section.

\input{sec-two}

\end{document}
```

In this example, using the `beamerarticle` class all looks fine, but with the `beamer` class activated with the specified option, nothing but the title frame will be created. The two additional files do contain valid LaTeX code with frames!

Comment: As Vedran has commented in https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/130/ignorenonframetext-and-include, this is a lot trickier than it looks! Catching the `\input` is fine, but ensuring that the correct mode continues after input is much more awkward. I'm a bit busy this weekend, but I will make an effort to sort this over the next few days.

Comment: @JosephWright: Do you see any problems with my suggestion?

Comment: @Marco Nothing wrong with it, but really this behaviour should be sorted at the class level.

Comment: @JosephWright: But then you need two different `input` commands. One for input `frame` and one for input `text`.

Comment: @Macro I'm quite sure I follow: `\input` should always include the referenced file as though it was 'typed in here'.

Comment: I agree with Joseph Wright about the "class level". Marcos solution is quite working, but to take full advantage of it, I must save any frame in a single file to be able to print additional text between two frames. Otherwise it's just possible to place the explanations on the highest level.

Comment: The new link to the issue mentioned in @JosephWright's first comment is https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/130

Answer (score 12):

In the [documentation of `beamer`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/) on pages 211 and 212 you find the explanation and also an example. To use `input` or `inlcude` with the option `ignorenonframetext` you must enable `ignorenonframetext` for this part. `\mode*` is equivalent to the option `ignorenonframetext`. You can enable it with `\mode<all>` or `\mode<presentation>`.  Here an example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sec-one.tex}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sec one}
  foo
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sec-two.tex}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sec two}
  foo
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{scrartcl} \usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\title{Test slides}
\author{Christoph Juengling}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\mode<all>
\input{sec-one}
\mode*
This is explaning text at the end of the first section.

\input{sec-two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I understand this, (1) every input command has to be bracketed with \mode<all> ... \mode* and (2) the additional text must be between a \mode* and the next \mode<all> on the highest level!

Comment: @ChristophJüngling: With the option `ignorenonframetext` you set `\mode*` global. To use `input` you must deactivate `\mode*`. This is done by `\mode<all>`. Now no text will be ignored. But you want to use the option `ignorenonframetext` further so you must activate `\mode*`. I hope you understand my English ;-)

Comment: There is no problem with your english, and I quite understand the mechanisms behind this a little better now. My previous knowledge was that `\input` just inserts the file's content as if it were written here. Your solution doesn't solve my whole problem, because commented text between frames in an \inputted :-) file is nevertheless printed on a slide, too.

Comment: @ChristophJüngling: In the link documentation you find the following sentences: *The difference is that the text is now read token-wise, not line-wise. The text is gobbled token by token until one of the following tokens is found: `\mode`, `\frame`, `\againframe`, `\part`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\appendix`, `\note`, `\begin{frame}`, and `\end{document}`*

Comment: I read some more in the beamer's documentation, and I suppose that `\mode<article>{Extra detail mentioned only in the article version.}` would do the job best for me. I can place this in any position between frames and in files that are read via `\input`, and for the moment, this looks very good. Ok, it's some extra stuff to type, but that's quite ok.

Comment: @ChristophJüngling: Of course, it is an other possibility.

Comment: You do not need the `\mode*` commands, if you use `\mode<all>{\input{filename.tex}}`.