# Is standalone compatible with ignorenonframetext beamer's option?

Tags: beamer, standalone, beamerarticle

Until now I've been using `standalone` to produce cropped figures which are included with `\includegraphics` command in beamer presentations and articles (`beamerarticle`) compiled from same source file. Today I wanted to use `standalone's` possibility of also creating figures and not only including them but as soon as I include `ignorenonframetext` option for `beamer` class something breaks. I've read about `beamer` option for `standalone.cls` but i don't draw 'animated' figures so I think I don't need it.

Next you have a minimal working and not working example: it works with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

but not if `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}` combines with `\input{figure}`. If instead of `\input` I place `TiKZ` code inside the frame works again even with `ignorenonframetext`.

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{filecontents}{figure.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) rectangle (3,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Hello}
\input{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error message says:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \documentclass
                  [tikz]{standalone}
? e
```

Some final comments. I've used `filecontents` package to simplify the example, real figure files are independent one's. I don't know if frame option `fragile` is necessary or not. I've also tested with `\mode<all>` before `\input` as is suggested in [\input{...} is ignored with beamer option ignorenonframetext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/input-is-ignored-with-beamer-option-ignorenonframetext) but nothing changes.

*Update*

Although `egreg` answer is valid for the MWE, this was too minimal because as soon as a second nesting level is introduced, `\sainput` fails. Next you have a new not so minimal working example. In this case, main document `\input` a file which `\input` the `standalone` figure. Everything works with `article+beamerarticle` or `beamer`, but not with `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}`. In this last case, `pdflatex` finishes and `*.log` doesn't show any error except `No pages of output.` and resulting `*.pdf` has 0 size.

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\sainput{\let\documentclass\sa@documentclass\input}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{figure.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) rectangle (3,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{doc.tex}
\begin{frame}{This is a frame}

Here, there is a TiKZ figure

\input{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\input{doc}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `ignorenonframetext` option messes up what `standalone` does for avoiding reading a preamble.

This seems to be a workaround:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{filecontents}{figure.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) rectangle (3,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\sainput{\let\documentclass\sa@documentclass\input}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello}
\sainput{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't redefine `\input` but if you're bold you can try

```
\makeatletter
\let\latexinput\input
\def\input{\let\documentclass\sa@documentclass\latexinput}
\makeatother
```

instead of the `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` group as before and use `\input{figure}`.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works with the minimal example, but not when a second nesting level is introduced. I've updated my question.