# Defining a new environment in beamer results in errors

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, environments, biber, presentations

I tried searching for an answer for a few weeks now but never quite got a satisfying result so I guess, I should ask myself.

I work in a project where we use a project-specific class to generate presentation slides. A specific environment that is defined in the class file is the so called bibFrame, basically an environment that gathers all the references. Right before this, the contactFrame is used to thank the audience for their attention and contact data is presented. Whenever I compile these into a PDF, an error occurs (but a PDF is produced nevertheless):

`! LaTeX Error: \begin{bibFrame} on input line XX ended by \end{document}.`

I built some minimal examples. The `test.cls` file looks like this. The `ignorenonframetext` is very important, as we write comments between the slides.

```
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage[style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\NewEnviron{contactFrame}[7][]{
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{center}
\huge\textbf{\BODY}
\end{center}
\vfill
\textbf{Contact:}\\
{#2} \\
{#3} \\
{#4} \\
{#5} \\
{#6} \\
\end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\NewEnviron{bibFrame}[1][]{
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{#1}
\BODY
\end{frame}
}
```

The content of the file `test.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item \cite{A}
\item \cite{B}
\item \cite{C}
\item \cite{D}
\item \cite{E}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{contactFrame}{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}
    Thank you for your attention!
\end{contactFrame}

\appendix

\begin{bibFrame}{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{bibFrame}

\end{document}
```

And finally the content of `literature.bib` looks like this (although you could replace that by any literature reference list you prefer):

```
@inproceedings{A,
author = {Kleppmann, Martin and Wiggins, Adam and van Hardenberg, Peter and McGranaghan, Mark},
title = {Local-First Software: You Own Your Data, in Spite of the Cloud},
year = {2019},
isbn = {9781450369954},
publisher = {Association for Computing Machinery},
address = {New York, NY, USA},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1145/3359591.3359737},
doi = {10.1145/3359591.3359737},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2019 ACM SIGPLAN International Symposium on New Ideas, New Paradigms, and Reflections on Programming and Software},
pages = {154–178},
numpages = {25},
keywords = {data ownership, collaboration software, CRDTs, peer-to-peer communication, mobile computing},
location = {Athens, Greece},
series = {Onward! 2019}
}

@manual{B,
 author = {ACM/IEEE},
 organization = {Joint Task Force on Computing Curricula, Association for Computing Machinery (ACM) and IEEE Computer Society},
 title = {Computer Science Curricula 2013: Curriculum Guidelines for Undergraduate Degree Programs in Computer Science},
 year = {2013},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-2309-3},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
    
@manual{C,
 author={ACM},
 organization = {K-12 Computer Science Framework Steering Committee led by the Association for Computing Machinery, Code.org, Computer Science Teachers Association, Cyber Innovation Center, and National Math and Science Initiative in partnership with states and districts},
 title = {K-12 Computer Science Framework},
 year = {2016},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-5278-9},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 url={https://www.k12cs.org/}
}

@book{D,
  title={{PISA Programme for international student assessment (PISA) PISA 2000 technical report: PISA 2000 technical report}},
  author={Adams, Ray and Wu, Margaret},
  year={2003},
  publisher={OECD Publishing}
}

@article{E,
  title={{Problem solving and the development of abstract categories in programming languages}},
  author={Adelson, Beth},
  journal={Memory \& cognition},
  volume={9},
  number={4},
  pages={422--433},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Running `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` on `test.tex` gives me the described error. Also, I minimized it a lot, so now the contactFrame is completely suppressed (but I don't know why). Placing it into the appendix would show the contactFrame but suppress the bibFrame. Does anyone see any mistake we made?

Kind regards and thanks for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can put `\mode<all>` or `\mode<presentation>` before and `\mode*` behind your self-defined environments to show them, see [\input{...} is ignored with beamer option ignorenonframetext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29353/123129).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will quote the comment of [dexteritas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/123129/dexteritas), as it contained all the necessary information to solve the problem:

> You can put `\mode<all>` or `\mode<presentation>` before and `\mode*` behind your self-defined environments to show them, see [\input{...} is ignored with beamer option ignorenonframetext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29353/123129)

Thank you so much. I hope this is of help for other people with a similar problem.